# Speed up creation of mysql table (from select)

Tags: mysql, performance, temp-tables

I've got a query that runs in about 1.6 seconds and returns 150Kish rows.  I have been building a memory engine based temp table from this query and this operation takes about 6.5 seconds.  I've sifted through lots of documentation on the mysql site as well as futzed with indexes on the temp table (hardly any difference at all when I have indexes vs not having them) trying to find some way for the table creation to be a bit better performing.  Does anybody have any suggestions with respect to config options that may speed up creating an in memory temp table (or non temp table)?  To clear up what exactly I'm looking for (I think) is some sort of table config options that may increase the speed of the creation.  I've gone through most of the ones listed on the mysql 5.7 site but nothing seems to change the time it takes to create the temp/standard table in memory.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE 
IF NOT EXISTS myTempTable 
(ugID INT,stID INT, INDEX st (`st`) ) 
ENGINE=MEMORY AS 
select ugID, stID 
from a_complex_query_that_runs_in_under_2_seconds_but_takes_6_to_write_to_a_temptable_with_150k_rows


id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived15> ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    559 
1   PRIMARY creatorEntity   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   creatorAssignment.OwnerObjectID 1   Using index
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    152580  Using where; Using join buffer
15  DERIVED VMAssignment    ref AssociatedObjectID,AssociatedObject AssociatedObject    2       2902    Using where
2   DERIVED test_   range   AssignmentValue,AssociatedObjectID,AssociatedObject,assignmentQuery AssociatedObjectID  4   NULL    214 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED cfv_    ref CustomFieldID,EntityID,CFEntity,CFValue,CFEntityValue   CustomFieldID   4   testCloud.test_.AssignmentValue 4232    Using where
2   DERIVED ent_    ref VMStoreID   VMStoreID   4   testCloud.cfv_.EntityID 1   Using index
3   UNION   test_   ref AssociatedObjectID,AssociatedObject AssociatedObject    2       2902    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
3   UNION   cfv_    ref CustomFieldID,EntityID,CFEntity,CFValue,CFEntityValue   CFValue 772 func,func   4   Using where
3   UNION   ent_    ref VMStoreID   VMStoreID   4   testCloud.cfv_.EntityID 1   Using index
4   UNION   test_   const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4       1   Using index
5   UNION   test_   index_merge AssociatedObjectID,AssociatedObject AssociatedObjectID,AssociatedObject 4,6 NULL    1   Using intersect(AssociatedObjectID,AssociatedObject); Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
5   UNION   entity_ ref PRIMARY,ClassName   ClassName   2       23326   Using where
5   UNION   ent_    ref VMStoreID   VMStoreID   4   testCloud.entity_.ID    1   Using index
6   UNION   entity_ ref PRIMARY,ClassName   ClassName   2       23326   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
6   UNION   ent_    ref VMStoreID   VMStoreID   4   testCloud.entity_.ID    1   Using index
6   UNION   test_   ref AssignmentValue,AssociatedObjectID,AssociatedObject,assignmentQuery AssignmentValue 768 testCloud.entity_.State 1   Using where
7   UNION   entity_ ref PRIMARY,ClassName   ClassName   2       23326   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
7   UNION   ent_    ref VMStoreID   VMStoreID   4   testCloud.entity_.ID    1   Using index
7   UNION   test_   ref AssignmentValue,AssociatedObjectID,AssociatedObject,assignmentQuery AssignmentValue 768 testCloud.entity_.Zip   1   Using where
8   UNION   test_   range   AssociatedObjectID,AssociatedObject AssociatedObjectID  4   NULL    150 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
8   UNION   entity_ ref PRIMARY,ClassName,Address   Address 456 func,func   4   Using where
8   UNION   ent_    ref VMStoreID   VMStoreID   4   testCloud.entity_.ID    1   Using index
9   UNION   test_   range   AssignmentValue,AssociatedObjectID,AssociatedObject,assignmentQuery AssociatedObjectID  4   NULL    203 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
9   UNION   ent_    ref VMStoreID   VMStoreID   4   testCloud.test_.AssignmentValue 1   Using where; Using index
10  UNION   test_   const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4       1   Using index
11  UNION   test_   ref AssociatedObjectID,AssociatedObject AssociatedObjectID  4       1   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
11  UNION   entity_ ref PRIMARY,ClassName   ClassName   2       23326   Using where
11  UNION   ent_    ref VMStoreID   VMStoreID   4   testCloud.entity_.ID    1   Using index
12  UNION   test_   ref AssignmentValue,AssociatedObjectID,AssociatedObject,assignmentQuery AssociatedObject    2       2902    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
12  UNION   ent_    ref VMStoreID   VMStoreID   4   testCloud.test_.AssignmentValue 1   Using where; Using index
13  UNION   test_   range   AssignmentValue,AssociatedObjectID,AssociatedObject,assignmentQuery AssociatedObjectID  4   NULL    239 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
13  UNION   list_stores ref VMListID,VMStoreID,VMStoreID_2,VMStoreID_3,VMStoreID_4,VMStoreID_5,VMStoreID_6,VMStoreID_7,VMStoreID_8,VMStoreID_9,VMStoreID_10,VMStoreID_11,VMStoreID_12,VMStoreID_13,VMStoreID_14,VMStoreID_15,VMStoreID_16   VMListID    4   testCloud.test_.AssignmentValue 318 Using where
13  UNION   ent_    ref VMStoreID   VMStoreID   4   testCloud.list_stores.VMStoreID 1   Using index
14  UNION   test_   range   AssignmentValue,AssociatedObjectID,AssociatedObject,assignmentQuery AssociatedObjectID  4   NULL    70  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
14  UNION   sto_    ref PRIMARY,RetailerID  RetailerID  4   testCloud.test_.AssignmentValue 63  Using where; Using index
14  UNION   ent_    ref VMStoreID   VMStoreID   4   testCloud.sto_.ID   1   Using index
NULL    UNION RESULT    <union2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14>   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: What version of MySQL? Also, please post your schema and an `EXPLAIN` on the `SELECT`.

Comment: mysql version 5.6.  Posting the explain in the original post, but just to be clear ... the problem doesn't really seem to be the query, but the time that it takes the query to populate the temp table (I could, of course, not be understanding that something about the underlying query could speed up the temp table creation but in the end the time to create the temp table seems to be mostly related to the number of rows coming back)

Comment: The explain is not meant to necessarily include or exclude the query as the slow point but rather to provide information about the contents of your table as a proxy to knowing the actual rows.

Comment: How long does it take to copy the resulting table into a new (equal) table?

Comment: It looks like all the UNIONs and their implicit sorting is expensive, each one requiring a disk sort.  Try increasing sort_buffer_size for your session `SET @@sort_buffer_size=16777216;` to see if you can get the intermediate sorts to be done in RAM.  How are you timing the 1.6 seconds?  Is it that you run the query and get results in a tool like MySQL workbench, which could be only first n rows?  Or is it 1.6 seconds to see all columns of all records?

Comment: I have done some experimenting on different sort_buffer_size settings and got it down to where I had 0 sort merge passes but it never helped the speed.  I will, however do some more experimenting just to be double sure of my initial results because tbh, I think I may have just been doing that experimentation with the query and not the create table portion as well.  Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

There is not much there to work with.  (`SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN`)  But I do see one thing:

```
Using intersect(AssociatedObjectID,AssociatedObject)
```

That can almost always be improved by using a 'composite' index:

```
INDEX(AssociatedObjectID, AssociatedObject)
```

There may be other cases for composite indexes, but we would need to see the query.

"but the time that it takes the query to populate the temp table" -- Creating the 152K rows is likely to take longer than inserting that many rows.

Try `ENGINE=InnoDB` instead of `ENGINE=MEMORY`.  InnoDB has made performance strides.

Also try not including `INDEX st (st)` in the `CREATE`, but adding it afterwards.  Building the index incrementally *may* be the slowest part of the `CREATE`.

There are probably no tunables that affect performance of `MEMORY`.

Comment: Thanks Rick.  From earlier testing the innodb table takes about 15% longer to create than the memory table.  I will try and clean up that index though and see if that helps any.  I'll also give the delayed index a try although when I create the table without the index it takes nearly the same amount of time ~5%

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; that is interesting to know.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to figure out where the bottleneck is. As others have suggested in the comments, it isn't in filling up the temporary table.

### Inserting 150k rows

This takes about 5 seconds. Woah, which leaves me looking foolish, but I will redeem myself later.

```
   $dbh->query('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTempTable (ugID INT,stID INT, INDEX st (`st`) r ');
   $dbh->beginTransaction();

   $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO myTempTable(ugId,stID) values(:u, :s)");

   for ($i=0; $i < 150000 ; $i++) {
       $stmt->execute(array("u"=> $i, "s"=> $i));
   }
   $res = $dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) from myTempTable");

   $dbh->commit();
```

### CREATE TABLE LIKE

The above experiment is a poor one because it's looping 150k times and indeed it maybe. But what if we created a permanent table as above and then did CREATE TABLE LIKE (this is the original problem after all)

BTW Removing the `TEMPORARY` keyword from the above code increased the time to about 9 seconds. And now in the mysql console.

```
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS myTempTable  (ugID INT,stID INT, INDEX st (`stId`) )  ENGINE=MEMORY AS (SELECT * FROM ugTable);
Query OK, 150000 rows affected (0.17 sec)
Records: 150000  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Fraction of a second. So clearly what's at fault is the way that the data is loaded rather than the process of filling up the table.

### Reduce IO.

Your complex query reads a lot of row. 150k rows in a set of large tables is a lot of IO. You can speed this up a great deal by making sure that the server has enough memory to cache the entire set of tables involved here in memory.

That would be a lot easier, if the size of the data on disk was smaller. Perhaps time to re examine your tables and see if there is a normalization  step you missed. Time to see if some of the indexes can be changed. For example you have some hefty indexes like `AssignmentValue 768`. Even when these indexes are used, that's still quite a lot of IO.

All this data has to be read on disk before loading up 150k of them into the temporary table which is in memory.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to create the index after the table has been populated with your data. This will reduce your runtime. Theory behind this is that the index will be created as a whole in memory after the insert and will then be written to disk which is a lot faster than updating the index with every insert. The index will also have a perfect tree layout when created after the insert.